# How to add server to the list in Starcraft brood war (Ubuntu, Wine)

Tags: 12.10, wine, games

I'm running Starcraft via Wine. It runs perfectly, but I don't know how to add an entry to the list of servers. In Windows it's added via reg file.

Answer (score 3):

Starting regedit is`wine regedit`

In regedit I have a key called "battle.net gateways" in: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Battle.net\Configuration

I hope that is of help.

Another place where you could start looking for the correct place in the registry is iCCup.com. ICCup is a ladder for broodwar that has its own ladder server (that has to be configured in the registry).

[iCCup's guide to getting started](http://www.iccup.com/starcraft/sc_start.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, what exactly should I add to "battle.net gateways" to enable iccup.com?

Answer (score 2):

**Playonlinux** supports a *Regedit* application, meaning you would have to tweak the registry manually.

You can find **Playonlinux** in the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple command:

```
wine regedit yourfile.reg
```